# Magento - 404 error in public product page

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, http-status-code-404

I have a Magento 1.7 web width 2 stores in different languages width a direffent domain for each store.

When I enabled products for the second store, the public product pages of the second store stopped functioning. Now are 404 error, but the first store product pages continue to perform well.
All other pages work correctly.

http://www.bioaigua.es/grower-abono-de-crecimiento.html - OK

http://www.bioaigua.net/rooty-enhances-the-formation-of-roots.html - 404 error

Any idea?

Comment: I have read many solutions, but none work

Comment: Maybe you have problems with short Urls and the index. Did you set up the second store after your product import.

Comment: Also interesting that you edit you live system :D

Comment: What root category did you set up for both stores?

Comment: @Silom - How can i fix the short Urls and the index problems? I created the products before create the second store. Then I added the products to the second store too.

Comment: @Silom - What is 'edit live system'?

Comment: @MarceliPo - The root category for the 2 stores is 'Default category'

Comment: If you got to 'System -> index Management' you will see all magento Indexes. Now you reindex them. Maybe this helps.

Comment: **I've solved !!!** The problem was the meta of Facebook. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 10):

Go to your DB and run this SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO `report_event_types` (`event_type_id`, `event_name`, `customer_login`) VALUES
(1, 'catalog_product_view', 1),
(2, 'sendfriend_product', 1),
(3, 'catalog_product_compare_add_product', 1),
(4, 'checkout_cart_add_product', 1),
(5, 'wishlist_add_product', 1),
(6, 'wishlist_share', 1);
```

P.S. check DB name prefix if you have it!

Comment: Wow! worked like a charm! My exception.log file was getting REPORT_EVENT_TYPE errors, which made me think your solution would work. I tried and it did! Thanks!

Comment: thanks this worked for me, does this happen when someone accidentally truncates report_* tables out of habit when cleaning logs in the DB?

Comment: Why does this occur?

Comment: I was told all log_* and report_* tables were not required when migrating a magento site for developement purposes. That was wrong and this query fixed my issue as well.

Answer (score 4):

Go to *Mage\Catalog\controllers\ProductController.php* and change `viewAction()` actions code:

from (line 140)

```
} else {
     Mage::logException($e);
     $this->_forward('noRoute');
}
```

to

```
} else {
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($e);
    Mage::logException($e);
    //$this->_forward('noRoute');
}
```

Then load product view, you can see the exception variable(in my case it was missing block, so I deleted it from one of layout .xml file). After finding the reason, you must restore code of `viewAction()`.

Answer (score 0):

Go to catalog > URL Rewrite Management and search the url you are having problems.

delete the rule that it is generating the problem